# Return value from Ant

Tags: ant

I am in the process of setting up hudson with already existing Ant scripts so I would be using a custom workspace. However, I would like to have a python script set some environment variables, call Ant with the top level build file and perform some other actions if the build was successful. Is there a way I can have ant return a true/false value based on the build status so that I can make appropriate decisions and perform related actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant will return a non-zero exit value if you use the `<fail>` task. The `<fail>` task can be combined with the `<condition>` task too:

```
<fail message="Missing file &quot;${foo}&quot">
    <condition>
       <not>
           <available file="${foo}" type="file"/>
       </not>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

You can use this to verify that what you were attempting to build was actually built, and if not, exit the build with an error.

If you don't want to fail immediately, you can use the `<condition>` task to set a property, and then fail if that property is set:

```
<fail message="Property foo.failed was set">
    <condition>
        <isset property="foo.failed"/>
    <condition>
</fail>
```

Or simply:

If Python isn't picking up the fail status, you can set an exit value on failure too:

Ant will return a non-zero exit status too f a build halts because a task fails. Many Ant tasks have a *haltonfailure* or *failonerror*, and the default is not to halt or fail on an error.

Comment: You are missing a "/" in second tag: `</condition>`.